# System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException：'validation of one or more entities failed

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Problem of insert data to database :

e.g:  goods.GoodPhoto = "/Content/img/imageGood/"+imageName;
         replace it with this：goods.GoodPhoto=""+imageName;
         and it worked.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddGoods(Good goods)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files["image"];
                string SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/imageGood/");
                string imageName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString()+image.FileName;
                image.SaveAs(Path.Combine(SavePath, imageName));
                goods.GoodPhoto = "/Content/img/imageGood/"+imageName;
                goods.ShopID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ShopID"]);
                db.Goods.Add(goods);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Once I code “ goods.GoodPhoto = "/Content/img/imageGood/"+imageName;” and then it failed. And Error message is :

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'validation
>   of one or more entities failed. For more information, see the
>   EntityValidationErrors property. '

Comment: What does Exception.EntityValidationErrors contain?

Comment: sorry，i  am a freshman

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add try catch to find to an exact error message

```
try
  {
     db.SaveChanges();                  

   }
 catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
 {
 foreach (var valErrors in e.EntityValidationErrors)
       {
         foreach (var errors in valErrors.ValidationErrors)
          {
            //here you will get property name and error message
                Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", 
                                errors .PropertyName, 
                                errors .ErrorMessage);
          }                  

       }
   throw;                 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a big help. Problem solved. ErrorMessage "field GoodPhoto must be of type string or array with a maximum length of" 50 ".

Comment: I am Glad to help you..!